# open cart language switcher to use both english and chinese from adding a snippet in the header.tpl

Tags: php, templates, header, opencart

I have a website who is in English. I added the chinese plugin with ftp in the server and added this snippet to my header.tpl under view/common.

EN  
            
            
                繁

I can see that a button was created with EN but when I click on it it takes me to the homepage which is still in english.

Comment: Post some code so we can see analyze whats wrong.

Comment: Hi Erik here is the snippet I used :

Comment: @ErikKralj I added the snippet below in my header.tpl and an extension for chinese language in my cms. The only thing I can see is a button in top corner who redirects me to the second link of the snippet

Comment: @ErikKralj <div class="language pull-right"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://com/index.php?route=module/language"><div id="language"> <div onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'en'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" class=" lang-btn">EN </div><div onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'zh_HK'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" class=" active  lang-btn"> 繁</div><input type="hidden" value="" name="language_code"><input type="hidden" value="http:///index.php?route=error/not_found" name="redirect"></div></form></div>

Comment: Don't post code snippets in comments, edit your question instead.